# How can I get the value of function arguments to be inserted in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am passing the values to function to insert data in database.

```
def add_user(id,username,cell,address):
    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address,cell) VALUES (%s, %s,%s)"
    val = ("John", "Highway 21","abc")
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

i-e 
I am adding user having only cellphone not address

```
add_user('shahid','03131234567')
```

then other user have only address

add_user('David','New York')

How can I handle that 2nd value is for address or cell phone field
THanks in ADvance.

Comment: Insert expects all fields in the correct order - send nulls for missing fields (assuming table allows nulls)Speaking with my machine mind I can't work out if only 2 fields are provided where the second is supposed to go.

Comment: for example i am passing the username and address only How can i handle it in a function that 2nd value is address not cell.

Comment: You can't they are just strings - you might assume something that is all numbers is a cell but I don't know if that would be a valid thing to do.Bit tricky if there are whitepspaces

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE2

Try this:

```
def add_user(id, *new_user):
    new_user = new_user[0]
    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,cell, address) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (new_user.get('username'), new_user.get('cell'), new_user.get('address'))
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)


user1 = {'username': 'user1', 'cell': '123345', 'address': 'fake address 12'}
add_user(1, user1)
user2 = {'username': 'user1', 'address': 'fake address 12'}
add_user(2, user2)
```

Comment: is it not possible to get arguments value in a loop and store in a object?
What you will say ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary using *args and **kwargs and then concatenate the keys and the values with `join()` and `map()`:

```py
def add_user(*args, **kwargs):
    saved_args = locals()
    query_data = saved_args['kwargs']

    columns = ', '.join(map(str, query_data.keys()))
    values = ', '.join(map(repr, query_data.values()))
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO customers ({}) VALUES ({})".format(columns, values)))

add_user(username='David', cell='03131234567', address='New York')
```

That would generate the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO customers (username, cell, address) VALUES ('David', '03131234567', 'New York')
```